# Sonar-Upgrade from 3.5.1 to 3.6.2 failed

Tags: upgrade, sonarqube

I'm getting this error, when upgrading from 3.5.1 to 3.6.2.
We are using a Oracle-DB.

What can I do to solve this issues?
I've found no information with google, stackoverflow or the codehaus-jira.

```
 ==  MigrateViolationsToIssues: migrating ======================================
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/07/18 16:58:17 | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to convert violations to issues
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/07/18 16:58:17 |       at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.ConvertViolationsToIssues.execute(ConvertViolationsToIssues.java:62)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/07/18 16:58:17 |       at org.sonar.server.db.DatabaseMigrator.executeMigration(DatabaseMigrator.java:77)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/07/18 16:58:17 |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/07/18 16:58:17 |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/07/18 16:58:17 |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/07/18 16:58:17 |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/07/18 16:58:17 |       at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:450)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/07/18 16:58:17 |       at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:311)
[...]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type Query: INSERT INTO issues(id, kee, component_id, root_component_id, rule_id, severity, manual_severity, message, line, effort_to_fix, status, resolution,  checksum, reporter, assignee, action_plan_key, issue_attributes, issue_creation_date, issue_update_date, created_at, updated_at)  VALUES (issues_seq.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) Parameters: [[4d4eb093-1843-4f4c-b175-beca9f9c6eb3, 11750, 11699, 10286, INFO, false, '32' 
[...]
```

Comment: Hi, which versions of Oracle and JDBC driver are installed ?

Comment: Oracle 11g with 11g-JDK6-drivers (the newest one)

Comment: Tested with default settings of 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 64bit and ojdbc6.jar (v11.2.0.3.0). 
What is the type of the column RULE_FAILURES.MANUAL_SEVERITY ?

Comment: Can you also export System Info please ? See Configuration -> System Info -> Download in the top-right corner. Thanks

Comment: Sonar is not starting, so no system info can be provided. But: we've got Oracle Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.0.0 - Production.Ahh and: There is not manual_severity in RULE_FAILURES

Comment: Sorry, I meant RULE_FAILURES.MANUAL_VIOLATION.

Comment: You can export the System Info from 3.5.1, if still possible.

Comment: We have now went back to 3.5.1. So I can't look into the 3.6.2-Database :-). Here is my System-Information: http://www.file-upload.net/download-7857834/sonar_system_info.csv.html

Comment: Version does not matter for the column type. You can get in with 3.5.1.

Comment: Could you please approve my answer ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We finally reproduced the migration issue. It will be fixed in version 3.7 :
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4542

Thanks for your patience.