# Upgrade fails: Fail to execute database migration to Sonarqube 3.6.2

Tags: sonarqube

When I would to upgrade from Sonar 3.2 to Sonarqube 3.6.2. the upgrades fails
Int the log file I read the folowing line:

```
Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.ConvertViolationsToIssues
```

I use a MSSQL database, I read that someone got exactly the same error when he wanted to upgrade using an Oracle 10g database. I read that this problem will be solved in 3.7. Is this also applying to my problem? When 3.7 will be realeased?

With kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue indeed looks like 2 other ones listed on stackoverflow:

- [Sonar-Upgrade from 3.5.1 to 3.6.2 failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727802/sonar-upgrade-from-3-5-1-to-3-6-2-failed)
- [upgrade from sonarqube 3.5.1 to 3.6.2 fails on migration of postgres db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945283/upgrade-from-sonarqube-3-5-1-to-3-6-2-fails-on-migration-of-postgres-db)

(would need more log to be sure, but I'm almost 100% sure)

So indeed, it will be fixed with [SONAR-4542](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4542) that will be shipped with SonarQube 3.7, expected in a couple of days from now (around August 9th).