# Sonar - Upgrade to Sonar 3.7 fails

Tags: database, upgrade, sonarqube

Currently I'm running a Sonar 3.5.1 installation without issues. I would like to upgrade to the latest 3.7 release but after starting the setup procedure I get an error saying the database migration failed.

The message says:

- java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.ConvertViolationsToIssues

Sonar is running on:

- Windows 7 Pro - x64
- MSSQL 2008 R2 databaseserver
- MSSQL jtds-1.2.7

In [other listed calls on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081601/upgrade-fails-fail-to-execute-database-migration-to-sonarqube-3-6-2) it says there are some fixes on this part coming with release 3.7.

Here is the logged error:

---

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/08/21 12:04:09 | ==  MigrateViolationsToIssues: migrating ======================================
2013.08.21 12:04:09 ERROR o.s.s.d.DatabaseMigrator  Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.ConvertViolationsToIssues
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to convert violations to issues
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.ConvertViolationsToIssues.execute(ConvertViolationsToIssues.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.sonar.server.db.DatabaseMigrator.executeMigration(DatabaseMigrator.java:78) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
[Cut some stacktrace info]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668) [jetty-io-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52) [jetty-io-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unable to identify the table TRUNCATE TABLE issues for the metadata. Query: TRUNCATE TABLE issues Parameters: []
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.rethrow(AbstractQueryRunner.java:363) ~[commons-dbutils-1.5.jar:1.5]
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.update(QueryRunner.java:490) ~[commons-dbutils-1.5.jar:1.5]
    at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.update(QueryRunner.java:376) ~[commons-dbutils-1.5.jar:1.5]
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.ConvertViolationsToIssues.truncateIssueTables(ConvertViolationsToIssues.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.ConvertViolationsToIssues.execute(ConvertViolationsToIssues.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 537 common frames omitted
2013.08.21 12:04:09 ERROR o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade  Fail to render: http://localhost:9000/setup/setup_database
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.ConvertViolationsToIssues
    org/sonar/server/db/DatabaseMigrator.java:83:in `executeMigration'
```

---

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this issue doesn't relate to https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4542 but is more contextual. After failing migration, do you see the 'issues' table in the SonarQube DB ?

Comment: Yes; there is an "issues" table.

Comment: In fact looks like you're not using the JDBC jTDS driver but the Microsoft driver, see "java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:..."

Comment: good point! I managed to run it using the jTDS driver and that fixed the issue. Is the other driver not supported at all in newer releases?

Comment: At least not tested so indeed not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in using the SqlServer JDBC Driver. Switching from the SqlServer driver to adviced jTSD driver fixed the issue.

Thanks to the Sonar Team.